# Unable to route to new_user_invitation page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

I'm having an issue with Devise invitable.

When I try to view the new invite page I get redirected to the users/sign_in page and get this in the console window:

```
Processing by Devise::InvitationsController#new as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

In my routes.rb file, I have this for the controllers setting:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :invitations => 'devise/invitations' }
```

Any idea on how I can fix this so I can view the new user invitation page?

Thanks

Comment: Is 'devise/invitations' your own home-spun controller?

Comment: It's not, I don't have a home-spun controller for this. I followed the setup instructions for DeviseInvitable and there are views that have been generated by the generators btw. but can't see any controller code I can debug.